# ffmpeg error loading shared OpenCV libraries

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, shared-libraries

I installed FFmpeg 3.3 from a PPA repository following the guide [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/05/install-ffmpeg-3-3-in-ubuntu-16-04-14-04/). I already have OpenCV 3.3 installed on my Ubuntu 16.04 system with all the necessary libraries under `/usr/local/lib`. However, when I try to run ffmpeg, I get the error:

```
ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: 
libopencv_core.so.2.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Does FFmpeg only work with OpenCV 2.4 libraries? I have the corresponding library for OpenCV under `/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.3.3` but somehow FFmpeg looks for the version 2.4.